# Java custom annotation to invoke some other method before invoking the annotated method

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, interceptor

I am trying to implement a custom annotation which looks something like :

```
public class Foo{

@CustomAnnotation(classname="com.somepackage.ExternalClass", methodname="method1", invokation="before")
public void bar(){
  //method body..
  }
}
```

The method specified in the annotation should be invoked before the actual method is invoked.
Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: IMO what you are doing here does not make a lot of sense. You are trying to re-implement things which you can do much more easily via AOP. But if you use AOP, why would you pollute your main application code with information about how to apply cross-cutting concerns? A clean solution would be to completely externalise this information into the aspects themselves and get rid of the reflection magic. Just let me know if you want to see a simple AspectJ example of what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish here?  Why wouldn't you just call the method from inside the method body?

Annotations are processed during compilation and available during runtime (if their lifetime is set to Runtime).  They can be used to generate code at compile time or to affect how other code treats your class, however you can't change existing classes during annotation processing.

The only thing you could do for this is if you are only calling that method from a single location, you can use reflection to check for that annotation and call the method (again, using reflection to call the method), similar to how JUnit works (with @Test and @Before/@After annotations).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AOP (AspectJ or Spring or Spring+AspectJ). the only thing which can be a problem is the `invokation="before"` annotation parameter because `before`, `after`, `around` etc. is advices which hardcoded in your aspects.
AspectJ code example below:

```java
public aspect CustomAnnotationAspect {

    pointcut customAnnotationPointcut(Object t, CustomAnnotation annotationValue): execution(@CustomAnnotation * *.*(..)) &&  @this(annotationValue) && target(t);

    before(Object target, CustomAnnotation annotationValue): customAnnotationPointcut(target, annotationValue) {
        String className = annotationValue.className();
        String methodName = annotationValue.methodName();
        //do some reflection staff for className.methodName() invocation
    }

}
```